# How can I add quotation marks to a libreoffice calc cell text?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

In libreoffice calc I have a column with thousand words. Each word I need to put into quotation marks.

Example (A1 and A2 are cells)

> start word (A1): car
>   end word (A2): "car"

Normally, I can reference cells and add new text with quotes.

Example

> = A1 & " wash"
>   A2: car wash

But how do I get quotation marks as part of the text? Example

> "car" wash

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to add quotes: use the **[`CHAR()`](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_CHAR_function)** function together with the correct [decimal ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/). CHAR(34) should return double quotes. You can insert the CHAR() function directly into a concat statement:

```
= CHAR(34) & A1 & CHAR(34) & " wash"
```

should combine the content of A1, nested into double quotes, and append " wash".

To modify the source data itself (in your example: no second column, modify the source column), you could use a search / replace with regular expressions. To do so:

1. Select the column containing the data to modify
2. select Menu "Edit" -> "Find & Replace..."
3. Enter `^(.*)$` as search text (matches the whole cell content) and `"$1"` as replace text (returns the complete search match, embedded in quotes):
   [image]
4. Hit <kbd>Replace</kbd> or <kbd>Replace all</kbd> to execute the search/replace run.

Comment: I know this will be deleted but I love you. You saved me a shlt tonne of time and tedium.

Answer (score 0):

It also works with `CONCAT` and escaping the quote sign:

```
=CONCAT("""", A1, """ wash")
```

To escape `"`, put another `"` in front of it, so `""` results in one double quote `"`. Putting this in a string results in `"""""` for one double quote.

[Using double quotation marks in formulas](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-GB/text/scalc/01/04060110.html#hd_id291624454173529)